# What do you call this oriental building in English?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What do you call this oriental building in English?

*Gazebo* or *pavilion* doesn't go with this building, I think...

[image]

Comment: I think it is a pagoda-like building.

Comment: Do you know the function of the building? I think pavilion is apt if it is essentially a shelter/place to rest: "A summer house or other decorative building used as a shelter in a park or large garden." (OED). Pagoda typically suggests a religious purpose.

Comment: Perhaps you could call it a [hall](https://www.travelchinaguide.com/attraction/beijing/forbidden-city/architecture-character.htm).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_pagoda

Comment: @Lawrence: I'm not saying that "hall" is wrong. However, I do think that "hall" is not understood to refer to that exact building. Similarly, we could say that the correct word is "building" (since it is in fact a building), but that seems to miss the point of the question: finding a name that aptly describes _this specific type of building_. Similarly, when "hall" is used, I would never think of this building; but rather something closer to a concert hall. "Hall", on the URL you linked, is synonymous with "large open space", which is not an apt description for this *specific* building.

Comment: Anapji Pond, Gyeongju, South Korea. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donggung_Palace_and_Wolji_Pond_in_Gyeongju

A reconstructed ***pavilion*** at Anapji lake. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donggung_Palace_and_Wolji_Pond_in_Gyeongju#/media/File:Anapji_Pond-Gyeongju-Korea-2006-07.jpg

Comment: *Pavilion* is too broad; *pagoda* is typically a sacred place; functionally and structurally it's quite different from a *gazebo*.

Comment: @Kris: In what sense is pavilion too broad? That image seems to be a good match

Comment: @Flater Yes, 'hall' sounds too generic. That's why I didn't make it a proper answer. However, I thought it was interesting that the names listed in the article included several 'hall's - Hall of Supreme Harmony, Hall of Central Harmony, etc. To my non-architect eyes, the OP's building resembled some of the architecture of those in the article - ornate roofs, 'open' feel, lots of pillars and some design elements at the top of the pillars. (PS: I agree that the word *hall* doesn't pull up the type of imagery presented by the OP, outside of that article's context.)

Comment: @sxpmaths: I'm not Kris; but an argument can be made that the OP is trying to communicate to English speakers, who will interpret "pavilion" as the more common western pavilion, not the oriental one that the OP is showing us. If the oriental style is essential to the word the OP is looking for, then pavilion is too broad (but that can be solved by an adjective to further specify it, as per my answer)

Comment: @Lawrence: I did note the recurring usage of hall on the site you linked, but I don't think that "hall" is particularly referencing the building (as seen from the outside), compared to what the inside is being used for. Most sources I find also define hall as a "relatively large space enclosed by a roof **and walls**.", and the OP's building quite notably lacks walls. "Hall" refers to a large inside space, not the building that it is found in.

Comment: Popularly, I'd guess that most Brits would come up with 'pagoda', but I think most travel mags use the term 'temple' if the function is religious.

Comment: @Flater Point taken. [This](http://www.historyforkids.net/ancient-chinese-architecture.html) link suggests that your *pavilion* is closer to the mark. That link mentions the lack of walls for those structures. I wonder whether the transliteration *ting* would be acceptable since the structure is so culturally distinctive.

Comment: @Lawrence: I agree that if the OP's intended word is _very specific_ (including usage of the building, architectural style, etc.), then the used word must also be _very specific_ and I'd be in favor of transliteration. However, there is an argument to be made that no English speaker (who lacks close knowledge of oriental architecture) would understand what is meant, and the OP's goal seems to be to find a word that is understood by English speakers.

Comment: It does not look like a Pagoda to me, as a US English speaker.  I would rather call it a "pavilion" or maybe "asian style pavilion" or something along those lines if it is important to stress the asian style architecture.  (You could also be specific, and call it a "Korean pavilion" if you don't want the generic "asian".)

Comment: It's a roofed porch.

Answer (score 47):

> **Disclaimer**
>   My answer is based on what a Westerner **would** call such a building (common usage), not on whether the origins of the word are factually correct.
>
> Somewhat analogous to how "citizen" technically refers to the inhabitant of a city, but we commonly understand that it can refer to the inhabitant of a nation as well.
>   Or, a bit more thematically linked to your example, why we call the mountain in Japan "Mount Ōyama", when "Ōyama" already inherently means mountain in Japanese. It's a westernization, it forgoes factual correctness in favor of using terminology that *feels* more correct to the ears of a Westerner.

My first instinct would be to call it a **pagoda**.

[Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagoda)

> A pagoda is a tiered tower with multiple eaves, built in traditions originating as stupa in historic South Asia and further developed in East Asia or with respect to those traditions, common to Nepal, India, China, Japan, Korea, Vietnam, Burma, Sri Lanka and other parts of Asia.

However, please do consider that this answer is from a Westerner's point of view. I'm not sure if a pagoda is an overgeneralization.
Similarly, Wikipedia lists a pagoda as a building with **multiple** tiers of eaves. I'm aware that the building in your picture only has one tier, but I doubt that anyone in the West would refrain from calling it a pagoda because it only has one tier.

Also, I'm not sure if you are focusing on the *specific* architecture of the picture you linked. As you can see on the Wikipedia page that I linked, pagodas come in different architectural styles.

---

From your suggestion, I do think that **pavilion** is a good option too.

[Merriam-Webster link](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pavilion)

> **3a** :  a usually open sometimes ornamental structure in a garden, park, or place of recreation that is used for entertainment or shelter
>   **3b** :  a temporary structure erected at an exposition by an individual exhibitor
>   *e.g. visited the **Chinese pavilion** at the international exposition*.

It's interesting that the example itself refers to a Chinese pavilion. Although the building in your picture looks more Japanese than Chinese, the Google Images results for Chinese pavilion are very close to it:

[image]

---

### Conclusion

I would favor calling it a **pagoda**, as this name makes an implication about its Oriental architectural style.
Doing some research on it now (because of your question), it seems that pagodas are inherently towers, and I would not describe the building in your picture as a tower.

Nonetheless, I do think that pagoda still applies, because I suspect that it will be interpreted by an English speaker to mean "*an ornamental building in an oriental style*", without necessarily expecting it to be a tower.

**Pavilion**, while correct, would be less understood by an English speaker (as they will primarily think you are talking about *western* pavilions). However, if you describe it as a **Japanese pavilion**, it seems almost equivalent to what most people think of as a pagoda.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I believe "Mt Fuji" isn't redundant; it's "Mt Fujiyama" that is. (For what it's worth, Wikipedia agrees with me here.)

Comment: @TimPederick: Good catch! First of all, I blame QI as they were the ones to inform me of the (apparently incorrect) tautology. However, I did just find that there is also a japanese mountain called Mount Ōyama, which is a better example then :)

Comment: I'm British and I would also identify that structure as a pagoda, regardless of whether or not that is technically correct.

Comment: I'm from Australia; I'd have called it a pagoda as well, unless I had a more specific term available to me.

Comment: _I got a girl in the Castle and one in the pagoda
You know I got rhymes like Abe Vigoda_

Comment: My default association with _pagoda_ would be multi-levelled; either _single-storey pagoda_ or _Japanese pavilion_ would probably work. And if we want (somewhat false) tautology, there's always [Torpenhow Hill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torpenhow_Hill).

Comment: @TripeHound; I specifically removed Torpenhow Hill (I had also remembered it from the same QI bit where I got the original Mount Fuji factoid from) because it's not a real place. Though I guess Torpenhow still counts anyway.

Comment: If I saw "Japanese pavilion" my interpretation would be that "pavilion" means definition 3b from your m-w definition and that "Japanese" was actually describing the "exhibitor"; I'm reasonably certain that's the intended interpretation of your m-w example. If you really want to use "pavilion", I'd say something more like "pavilion in a Japanese style" (or just "pavilion" if the architectural style isn't important in context)

Comment: @Walt: You're right, I see the ambiguity in my explanation. The example is in relation to an exposition stand. However, the picture I linked came from googling "Chinese Pavilion", and almost all resulting pictures show me this exact same building (which conforms to definition 3A). [Here's the results for "chinese pavilion"](https://www.google.be/search?q=chinese+pavilion&tbm=isch). It seems to me that the consistent results, coupled with the definition of 3A, make this an appropriate name for the building.

Comment: @Walt: As to your mention of  "pavilion in a Japanese style", I do think that "Japanese pavilion" is equally valid here (though less explicit, I'll give you that). Similarly, A Chinese restaurant can refer to the _cuisine_, not just the geographical location of the restaurant or the nationality of the owner.

Answer (score 2):

Normal practice would be to describe the building with the translation of the description in the native language.  That would describe the building's purpose.

There are no specific English words to describe specific types of architecture other than loan words from the relevant language.

That building looks familiar to me as one I have visited in Kyongju.  My understanding is that such buildings are meeting halls or ceremonial locations.  They would be described in that manner.

Answer (score 0):

A ceremonial or high court Pagoda, as opposed to an informal, or garden Pagoda (which would be rougher in style, without the ornamentation and embelishment of your example).